# Pandas - how to sort week and year numbers formatted as strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, data-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe like this, which sorted like:

```
>>> weekly_count.sort_values(by='date_in_weeks', inplace=True)
>>> weekly_count.loc[:9,:]

  date_in_weeks count
0   1-2013      362
1   1-2014      378
2   1-2015      201
3   1-2016      294
4   1-2017      300
5   1-2018      297
6   10-2013     329
7   10-2014     314
8   10-2015     324
9   10-2016     322
```

in above data, first column, all rows of `date_in_weeks` are simply "week number of a year - year". I now want to sort it like this:

```
  date_in_weeks count
0   1-2013      362
6   10-2013     329
1   1-2014      378
7   10-2014     314
2   1-2015      201
8   10-2015     324
3   1-2016      294
9   10-2016     322
4   1-2017      300
5   1-2018      297
```

How do i do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with a tutorial and the documentation,practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools needed to your solve your problem.

Comment: First step: tell whoever gave you this data to use ISO8601.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) with converted to datetimes with format `%W` week number of the year, [link](https://strftime.org/):

```
df = df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df['date_in_weeks'] + '-0',format='%W-%Y-%w').argsort()]
print (df)
  date_in_weeks  count
0        1-2013    362
6       10-2013    329
1        1-2014    378
7       10-2014    314
2        1-2015    201
8       10-2015    324
3        1-2016    294
9       10-2016    322
4        1-2017    300
5        1-2018    297
```

Comment: @anky_91 - yop, also not sure if minutes are good choice for week of years

Answer (score 3):

You can also convert to datetime , assign to the df, then sort the values and drop the extra col:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['date_in_weeks'],format='%M-%Y')
final = df.assign(dt=s).sort_values(['dt','count']).drop('dt',1)
```

---

```
print(final)

  date_in_weeks  count
0        1-2013    362
6       10-2013    329
1        1-2014    378
7       10-2014    314
2        1-2015    201
8       10-2015    324
3        1-2016    294
9       10-2016    322
4        1-2017    300
5        1-2018    297
```

Comment: Nice Anky, I tried doing `pd.to_datetime()` but must have missed the formatting as it failed.

Comment: @CeliusStingher yeah, format param helps in such cases :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using auxiliary columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_in_weeks':['1-2013','1-2014','1-2015','10-2013','10-2014'],
                   'count':[362,378,201,329,314]})
df['aux'] = df['date_in_weeks'].str.split('-')
df['aux_2'] = df['aux'].str.get(1).astype(int)
df['aux'] = df['aux'].str.get(0).astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(['aux_2','aux'],ascending=True)
df = df.drop(columns=['aux','aux_2'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  date_in_weeks  count
0        1-2013    362
3       10-2013    329
1        1-2014    378
4       10-2014    314
2        1-2015    201
```